# PHP cURL call works in Ubuntu 14.05 with PHP 5.5.9, but doesnt work on Ubuntu 12.04 with PHP 5.3

Tags: php, ubuntu, curl

I am having a problem calling cURL with php in my production server(Ubuntu 12.04, PHP 5.3).

It works on my localhost (Ubuntu 14.04, PHP 5.5.9)

This is the function which makes the cURL call.

```
public function callSendGrid($url,$method,$request_body = null)
{ 

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, ["authorization: Bearer ".$this->sendGridApiKey]);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    if($request_body)
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$request_body);

    switch($method){
        case 'PUT':
        case 'DELETE':
        case 'PATCH':
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
        break;
        case 'POST':
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        break;
        case 'GET':
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
        break;
    }

    $response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
    $http_status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    curl_close($ch);

    return ['status' => $http_status,'response' => $response];
}
```

I call it like

```
$this->Model->callSendGrid('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/campaigns/123123/schedules/now', 'POST');
```

It works on my local environment, but doesnt work on my production environment.

On my local environment, it returns

```
['status' => 201, 'response' => *a json decoded response*]
```

On my production environment, it returns

```
['status' => 400, 'response' => *absolutely nothing here*]
```

Its worth mention that some other calls work;

This call worked on both environments:

```
$this->Model->callSendGrid('https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/campaigns/', 'POST', 'a json that the api accepts');
```

I just cant see any difference between the two calls, except that the first one has no post data. But it shouldnt make it fail in one environment and work in another.

I am updating my production environment to match my local environment, but i didnt see any issues in cURL with PHP 5.3;

Im hoping you guys can help me. Its very odd to see the exact same call work in my local environment and dont work on my production environment, while other calls work on both environments. Its not a problem with the API that im making the call, since it works on local. I already have dumped the curl_response without json_decode it, it returns a BAD REQUEST on production environment.

Im really getting crazy here guys.

Thanks

Comment: SendGrid provides an API library, have you considered using that instead of writing your own with `curl`?

Comment: I have Barmar, but php 5.6 is a pre requisite for using they lib properly. My production server is PHP 5.3 :( 
We are already updating our php server in production though.

Comment: I've been using their library for a couple of years with 5.3. Did they update the library and add this requirement?

Comment: as seen on https://github.com/sendgrid/sendgrid-php:

Prerequisites
-  PHP version 5.6 or 7.0

But if its working with you, im gonna try

Comment: My copy is version 3.2, the github is 5.x. I guess I'm way out of date, but probably can't upgrade because of our PHP.